# Interference pattern of scalar wave around a Kerr black-hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, field-theory, interference, kerr-metric

If a scalar field is scattered around a Kerr black-hole, its amplitude will be amplified, keeping the frequency of the wave constant. So consider two waves; one is coming out from the horizon $(r_* \rightarrow -\infty)$ and another one from the infinity $(r_* \rightarrow +\infty)$. Clearly these two waves will interfere. I want to find the corresponding intensity distribution.

For that let us consider that the scalar wave can be decomposed as follows (keeping the symmetries in mind):

$\Phi(t,r,\theta,\phi) = \displaystyle\int \mathrm {d}\omega\, \! e^{-i\omega t}  \displaystyle\sum_{l,m}e^{im\phi}\dfrac{R_{lm}(r,\omega)}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}} S_{lm}(\theta,\omega)$

where $S_{lm}(\theta,\omega)$ denotes the [spheroidal wave functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroidal_wave_function) defined as,

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)\dfrac{dS_{lm}}{dx}\right] + \left[(cx)^2 + E_{lm} - \dfrac{m^2}{1-x^2}\right] S_{lm} = 0$; $x=cos\theta$ and $c=a\omega$

(details about the spheroidal wave functions can be found [here](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.73.024013)) and $R_{lm}(r,\omega)$ satisfies:

$\dfrac{d^2 R_{lm}}{dr_*^2} + \left[\dfrac{K^2 + \left(2am\omega-a^2\omega^2-E_{lm}\right)\Delta}{(r^2+a^2)^2} - \dfrac{dG}{dr_*} - G^2\right]R_{lm} = 0$;

where $K = (r^2+a^2)\omega-am$ , $G = \dfrac{r\Delta}{(r^2+a^2)^2}$ and $\dfrac{dr_*}{dr} = \dfrac{r^2+a^2}{\Delta}$ in [Boyer-Lindquist coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates).

So the intensity of the wave would (probably !!) be,

$I = \left|\displaystyle\int \mathrm {d}\omega\, \! \displaystyle\sum_{l,m}e^{im\phi}\dfrac{R_{lm}(r,\omega)}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}} S_{lm}(\theta,\omega)\right|^2 = \left| \displaystyle\sum_{l,m} \dfrac{e^{im\phi}}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}} \displaystyle\int \mathrm {d}\omega\, \! R_{lm}(r,\omega) S_{lm}(\theta,\omega) \right|^2$

Now how can this integral $\displaystyle\int \mathrm \! R_{lm}S_{lm} \, {d}\omega$ be proceeded? Is it possible to analytically proceed further? Or have one to carry the rest of the calculation numerically (though the numerical analysis of this would also be horrible, if it can't be analyically simplified further)? Any hint(s)?

**References of my calculations:**

1. Lecture Notes by Prof. Emanuele Berti at the summer school at ICTS (2016). [Black Hole Perturbation Theory](https://www.scribd.com/document/443855884/berteri-black-hole-perturbation-theory#).
2. Padmanabhan, T. (2010) Gravitation Foundation and Frontiers. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge.

Comment: “[Scattering of scalar waves by rotating black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0102100)” might be useful to look at.

Comment: Shouldn't your intensity depend on time?